# Passing ID value in autocomplete in Scriptaculous

Tags: php, javascript, scriptaculous

I have the scriptaculous autocompleter working. It pops up the data and I can select it, but it does not transfer the ID number in the form I'm using. I just cannot get the ID number. I can show the ID number on the screen using the following command:

```
alert (li.id);
```

I have used the following but no luck:

```
document.getElementById('inv_id').value=li.id;
```

and

```
$("#inv_id").val(li.id);
```

How do I pass that ID number to a value in the form? Here is the form code...

```
<form  action="page2.php" method="post" name="Add_Form">
<input type="hidden" name="inv_id" value="0">
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" name="autocomplete_parameter"/>
<div id="autocomplete_choices" class="autocomplete"></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

new Ajax.Autocompleter("autocomplete", "autocomplete_choices", "ajax_inv.php", {
  afterUpdateElement : getSelectedId
});

function getSelectedId(text, li) {

  alert (li.id); 
  document.getElementById('inv_id').value=li.id;
```

or

```
  $("#inv_id").val(li.id);

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Where is the `inv_id` field? Make it a hidden input if you don't have it existing already, then `document.getElementById('inv_id').value=li.id;` should work

Comment: I have line in my form: <input type="hidden" name="inv_id" value="0"> Sorry forgot to add it.

Comment: Add `id="inv_id"` to that tag. The functions you are using will find elements by ID but not NAME.